# Does anyone know what key combinations do we need to press to select all the text while renaming a file?

Tags: windows-vista

When renaming a file, I tried to do Ctrl-A (I wanted to select all then Ctrl-C copy).

However to my shock that shortcut doesn't work.

Does anyone know what key combinations do we need to press to select all the text while renaming a file?

(Windows Vista Home Premium sp2)

Comment: F2, works for me.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you have disabled "hide extensions of known file types?"

Comment: @keltari yes, but how does it affect the question?

Comment: @Pacerier, just explaining *why* its happening

Comment: Duplicates because it's the same question, but with different words

Comment: @keltari i mean how does it affect *why* its happening? (i've enabled it but nothing changes..)

Comment: Either it's a duplicate because it's the same intent, same actions, or NARQ because you're leaving out necessary information on what your set up is as to why that other doesn't appear to be the same

Comment: @random ic. i assure you it's neither of the first 2. i've updated the question with the necessary information and voted to reopen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press home, then press Ctrl-Shift-End

Comment: This answer is correct.  If you have disabled "hide extensions of known file types," then the highlighting stops at the extension of the file.  This is a safety feature to prevent breaking the association of the file accidentally.

Comment: btw why do you need Ctrl-Shift-End ? Shift-End seems to work fine for me

Comment: @keltari the Ctrl-A doesn't work regardless of whether the extension is selected or not, the Ctrl-A basically does nothing.

Comment: If the name wraps onto two or more lines you will probably need Ctrl-Home then Ctrl-Shift-End. Home will only take you to the beginning of the current line and Shift-End will only select to the end of the current line.

Answer (score 3):

Try what works in Windows 7 - use Shift-End